# Mac "zsh: permission denied" for an executable despite chmod changes to permissions and ability to double click on executable

Tags: macos, permissions, zsh, executable

There are plenty of "zsh: permission denied" questions, but I can't find anything to solve my problem. I want to run an executable called platon, which is in my path. If I type:

```
platon
```

I get:

```
zsh: permission denied: platon
```

I have tried

```
chmod +x platon
```

and I do not receive an error. However, I still cant execute the file. Running

```
sudo platon
```

gives

```
sudo: platon: command not found
```

even if I am in the directory that contains platon. Furthermore, I can actually execute platon by double clicking on the file. This pulls up the graphical interface for platon, but it is limited in functionality. what I actually need to do is

```
platon <filename>
```

which I can't get by double clicking on it. This is very puzzling, and any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't show the permissions. What does a `ls -l` or `stat` on the file say? Also, I suggest that you try to invoke the command by providing the path explicitly, to make sure that you are picking up the correct _platon_.